# Nested working set in myeclipse workbench

Tags: java, eclipse, myeclipse, working-set

I am using `MyEclipse Workbench 8.6` for my development environment. The workspace has around 30 projects categorized into several `Working Sets` each of which has a corresponding folder in the file system.

Is there a way in `MyEclipse` to create a nested `Working Set`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that this was implemented according to **[this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=102893)** bug report as long back as Eclipse 3.1

After some googling and comparing the release date of **[MyEclipse 8.5](http://jaxenter.com/myeclipse-8-5-released-11006.html)** and **[Eclipse Release dates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_software)**, I am guessing that your version of MyEclipse is based on Eclipse Helios ?

Also, **[this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=71128#c2)** seems to suggest that some work was done on this long back.

I also checked Eclipse JUNO and even that doesn't have the functionality of nested working sets.

Thus, out of the box, **there seems to be no way to do this**. 
**[Another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241701/nested-working-sets-in-eclipse-3-4)** asked on the same topic was never answered.

Comment: A [similar](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=37389) bug seems to have been closed without resolution.

Answer (score 0):

In the mean time a "Nested/Hierarchical view of projects" was implemented. See http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.5/M5/